# When is it necessary to escape a JavaScript bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, escaping, bookmarklet

Bookmarklets I've made seem to always work well even though I don't escape them, so why do bookmarklet builders like [John Gruber's](http://daringfireball.net/2007/03/javascript_bookmarklet_builder) escape special characters like space to `%20`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you copy/paste code into a bookmark using the browsers bookmark properties editor, you don't need to encode anything except newlines and percent signs. But, in fact, Firefox (and maybe other browsers) will encode spaces for you. If you check the properties again after saving, you'll see them encoded. You need to encode newlines because a bookmark can be only 1 line. You need to encode percent signs because the browser expects percent sights to always represent the first character in an encoded set. If you put the bookmarklet on a website in the `HREF` property of an `A` tag, the same rules apply, but you must also either HTML encode or URL encode any double quotes.

A lot of bookmarklet makers will just use encodeURIComponent, which encodes more than what is strictly necessary, but it might be considered more "correct".

Comment: Thanks! So instead of using `encodeURIComponent(js)`, I'm going to use `js.split('%').join('%25')`. No need to encode newlines 'cause I uglify the JS into one line first, and no need to encode double quotes manually 'cause when you do this: `anchorEl.href='javascript:alert("hi");'` the browser automatically escapes the `"`s into `%22`s.

Comment: In your href example you would need to URL encode or slash escape any single quotes.

Comment: True, but in my actual code I never have the JS in a string literal so it's not needed. Feel free to look at what I've been playing with: http://jsbin.com/speedy/3/edit?html,javascript,output It's a simple bookmarklet to change the speed of HTML5 videos. The bookmarklet `href` is automagically updated when you type in the JS panel.

Comment: The bookmarklet link didn't work in FF. Seems uglify is mangling the outer self executing function wrapper. I uglified the code myself and tested. I didn't know about the HTML5 range input type. Neat. Have you seen this? http://chriscinelli.github.io/youtube-video-speed-changer-bookmarklet

Comment: There, thanks! I fixed that: http://jsbin.com/speedy/3/edit?html,javascript,output