# How to properly encode script for bookmark

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a JS bookmark in Chrome that will automatically populate specific form fields on the page.

If I type the following in console, the text field with id 12345 gets populated with ABCDE.  This works with no problem as expected.

`document.getElementById('12345').value="ABCDE";`

However when I add the following to a bookmark and activate it on same page, nothing happens:

`javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.getElementById('12345').value%3D"ABCDE";%7D)`

The question I have is how to properly encode the script for inclusion in the bookmark so that it populates the field with the value.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it necessary to escape a JavaScript bookmarklet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066180/when-is-it-necessary-to-escape-a-javascript-bookmarklet)

Comment: Your bookmarklet creates an anonymous function but never calls it. Did you mean to create an IIFE?

Comment: YES!  That was it.  Added the necessary Grouping Operator () and it works.


`javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.getElementById('273612339_other').value%3D'JJs'%7D)();` - Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Just like the following:

`javascript:(function(){// code here})()` - you missed the last pair of brackets.

For fun, here's a bookmark that will work on a question page at SO. It entered the first 3 lines of this answer.

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('wmd-input').value="Just like the following:\n\n`javascript:(function(){// code here})()` - you missed the last pair of brackets.";})()
```